# Falling objects game in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently trying to make a game where my shapes will fall from the top of the screen down repeatedly for a set amount of time, so far I have managed to get my shapes to be able to fall down the screen but the point I'm struggling with is getting then to show up at the top again and repeat.

This code shows how I have drawn the shapes onto the screen.

```
def draw_window_one(star, triangle,rectangle,square,hexagon,circle):
    WIN.fill(WHITE)
    WIN.blit(GOLD_STAR, (star.x, star.y))
    WIN.blit(GREEN_TRIANGLE, (triangle.x, triangle.y))
    WIN.blit(LIGHT_BLUE_RECTANGLE, (rectangle.x,rectangle.y))
    WIN.blit(ORANGE_SQUARE, (square.x,square.y))
    WIN.blit(PURPLE_HEXAGON, (hexagon.x,hexagon.y))
    WIN.blit(RED_CIRCLE, (circle.x,circle.y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

And then this is the logic for it where I have made them fall down on the screen.

```
def main():
    star = pygame.Rect(75, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    triangle = pygame.Rect(575, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    rectangle = pygame.Rect(175, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    square = pygame.Rect(275, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    hexagon = pygame.Rect(375, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    circle = pygame.Rect(475, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        star.y += 1
        triangle.y += 1
        rectangle.y += 1
        square.y += 1
        hexagon.y += 1
        circle.y += 1
        draw_window_one(star, triangle,rectangle,square,hexagon,circle)

     pygame.quit()


 if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Think about how you would turn this statement into code "if the y position of my object is larger than the height of the screen then set the y position of the object to zero"

Comment: would that have to be in a while loop, in order for it to run for a certain amount of time? @flakes

Comment: Yes, you would check for the condition every iteration, in the same while loop that you perform the y increments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you can do. you can make an if statement if the object has a y value more than the screen height you can set the y value to be -1

```
if object.y > HEIGHT:
    object.y = -1
```

or as an alternative

```
if object.y > HEIGHT:
    del object
    object=ObjectClass()
```

this should be in your loop.